# Excluding/including strings in one re.compile statement in python to extract urls of interest

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

So I'm trying to get urls that contain specific strings, but also avoiding urls that contain a bad string.

So I don't want any urls that contain the string "/inventory/all/", and I only want urls that contain either the string "/inventories/" or "/inventory/2017/"

So I've managed to exclude at least the urls with strings that contain "/inventory/all/" by:

```
get_urls = soup.findAll('a', href=re.compile('^(?!.*/inventory/all/).*$'))
```

But when I try to include the strings I do want to get, then it no longer works, I tried:

```
get_urls = soup.findAll('a', href=re.compile('^(?!.*/inventory/all/).*$'|/inventories/|/inventory/2017/'))
```

Thanks for the help, I'm quite the novice

Comment: What does the `soup` object contain?

Comment: Do you have a cut-n-paste error or is that a syntax error with the extra single quote right before the first vertical bar: `.*$'|/inv` right in there.

Comment: yea, that didn't work I ended up solving via href=re.compile('^(?!.*/inventory/all/).*/inventories/.*$') ... thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following regex:

```
^(?=.*inventor(?:ies|y/2017))^(?:(?!inventory/all).)+$
```

- `^(?=.*inventor(?:ies|y/2017))` This is a look ahead that ensures that we are just looking for strings with either `inventories` or `inventory/2017`. For fewer backtracking, you need to anchor it ie `^` which shows that the matching should start at the beginning of the sentence. Thus just doing `^.*inventor(?:ies|y/2017).*$` should be enough since the only ones selected are the two.
- `^(?:(?!inventory/all).)+$` this part is a negative look ahead which asserts that from the beginning of the string to the end of the string there is no `inverntory/all`. I added this part in case you find a string that is of the format `inventoy/2017/inventory/all` This will be dropped.